# Fastest method to write a DataSet to a character delimited file

Tags: c#, performance, oracle11g

This is the fastest method I've found so far to retrieve a response recordset from an Oracle DB and write it out to a delimited file.  Faster would be even better.  Please offer suggestions.

Retrieving the result set:

```
using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ContextInfo.ConnectionString))
{
    oracleConnection.Open();
    try
    {
        using (var oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(extractToRun, OracleConnection))
        {

            oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oracleCommand.BindByName = true;
            oracleCommand.FetchSize = oracleCommand.FetchSize * 128;
            oracleCommand.InitialLONGFetchSize = 5000;
            oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(refCursorOracleParameter);
            oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(startDateOracleParameter);
            oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(endDateOracleParameter);
            oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(jobIdOracleParameter);

            using (var oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(oracleCommand))
            {
                oracleDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                return ds;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        oracleConnection.Close();
        oracleConnection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Processing the data and writing it out to the file:

```
public static void ExportDataTableToDelimitedFile(DataTable table, string filename, string encloseWith, string delimiter, bool includeHeader, string fieldsToExclude, bool fixedLengthValues)
{
    String excludeList = String.Empty;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldsToExclude))
    {
        excludeList = fieldsToExclude.ToUpper();
    }

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite, 131072, FileOptions.None))
    {
        BinaryWriter sw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            sw.Write(String.Empty);
            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        //Handle header
        if (includeHeader)
        {
            string header = String.Empty;
            String formattedHeader = String.Empty;
            foreach (DataColumn clm in table.Columns)
            {
                if (excludeList.Contains(clm.ColumnName.ToUpper()))
                    continue;

                if (clm.ColumnName.Length > 0)
                {
                    formattedHeader = String.Empty;
                    formattedHeader = encloseWith + clm.ColumnName + encloseWith;

                    if (header.Length > 0)
                        header = String.Join(delimiter, new string[] { header, formattedHeader });
                    else
                        header = formattedHeader;
                }
            }
            sw.Write(header);
        }
        // handle  values in data rows now
        Boolean hasEnlosedCharacter = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(encloseWith);
        ParallelOptions rowOptions = new ParallelOptions();
        rowOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        Parallel.ForEach(table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(), rowOptions, row =>
        {
            char[] rowValue = new char[8192];
            Int32 rowValueIndex = 0;

            string[] dcc = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
            foreach (String dc in dcc)
            {
                if (rowValueIndex > 0)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dc) && hasEnlosedCharacter)
                    {
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = delimiter[0];
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = encloseWith[0];
                        foreach (char c in dc)
                        {
                            rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = c;
                        }
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = encloseWith[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = delimiter[0];
                        foreach (char c in dc)
                        {
                            rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = c;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dc) && hasEnlosedCharacter)
                    {
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = encloseWith[0];
                        foreach (char c in dc)
                        {
                            rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = c;
                        }
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = encloseWith[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (char c in dc)
                        {
                            rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = c;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = '\r';
            rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = '\n';
            lock (sw)
            {
                sw.Write(rowValue, 0, rowValueIndex);
            }
        });
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
        table.Dispose();
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

I know that I should rename some of the variables and handle the header the same way (I'm not writing headers) so this is really a pure logic question and style answers don't help improve the performance.

The puzzling thing is the network performance.  It's only using 1.5% of the bandwidth when it's quickly returning 5 datasets with a few thousand rows?  I'm using the latest ODP.Net (Oracle) against an 11g DB.  I tried Devarts provider and it completely bombed for me.

[Network Performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phorF.jpg)

The processor load reflects the affect of the Parallel.ForEach over the rows within a datatable, which is a good thing.

[Processor Performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7qAX.jpg)

Comment: I'd recommend using the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) instead of disposing of the objects yourself, it's less error prone.

Comment: 1) you didn't show your query, so I cannot comment on its efficiency. 2) You did not show how the `DataTable` is populated from the `ds` variable, which you did not show being instantiated. 3) I do not know why your `fieldToExclude` variable is used after the data retrieval instead of using it to create an efficient query. With these restrictions, have you tried using a `StreamWriter`?

Comment: Actually, in most cases the time for retrieval of data from oracle DB should be a magnitude above any operation that is concerned with subsequent handling of data inside the datatable. So what are you actually interested in? (1) getting your data from oracle into datatable (2) getting your data from datatable into file (3) getting your data from oracle into file?

Comment: Actually the time it takes to retrieve the data from Oracle isn't bad.  I'm running 7 tasks in parallel to run 7 queries and return the datasets back to the main thread.  When one completes I call the procedure listed above (ExportDataTableToDelimitedFile) to write the contents out to a delimited file.  The queries return within a few seconds.  It DOES take time to bring the dataset back to the client though.  Around 30 seconds.  Total time to export 413K rows is 50 seconds.  We have a client who will be exporting many millions of rows though DAILY.

Comment: I've tried a multitude of other ways of converting a dataset into a char[] array, which is desirable because the binarywriter is by far the fastest stream writer.  It has a 16 mb buffer.  The line string[] dcc = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray(); dramatically improved the speed but isn't there a way to convert it into a char[][]?

Comment: Brian:  I did show how the datatable is being populated in the first code snippet.  It's using the dataset.fill method.  Later I'm passing into the 2nd code snippet ds.tables[0].  That's how it was converted to a datatable for the 2nd code snippet.

Comment: You state that the client is going to query for millions of records. Are you sure that the whole idea of pre-filling a datatable with all data is going to get you anywhere memory-wise? To me the whole thing looks like a case for `OracleDataReader` and writing data to file as you receive them, while async fetching the next set of data.

Comment: Regarding the network performance: Windows shows the local adapter speed, are you sure that the whole connection to the server is at 1 gbit strength?

Comment: grek40:  It's 1 gbit all the way to the server and the server has a 10 gbit connection to the network.  The network switches are high quality switches.  I've eliminated the scaler subqueries from the SELECT clause so the recordset should be prepared to simply return.  As for using the "fill" for millions of records, ODP.Net seems to do something about the size and manages it internally and it hasn't been a problem.  Would using a datareader be faster though?  I thought about it but then I can't parallel.foreach the rows.

Comment: 1. We agree with grek40: usage of OracleDataReader is the fastest way to read data from the database.
2. Terry Bill Bittner: "I tried Devarts provider and it completely bombed for me". Could you please describe the issue you have encountered with dotConnect for Oracle? Our contact form is available at https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html .

Answer (score 1):

THIS is the fastest I've been able to get it.

Retrieving the data:

```
public static DataTable GetData(String extractToRun, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    //RefCursor
    OracleParameter refCursorOracleParameter = new OracleParameter
                                            {
                                                ParameterName = "pCursor",
                                                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                                                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor
                                            };

    OracleParameter startDateOracleParameter = new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "pStartDate",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
        Value =   startDate
    };

    OracleParameter endDateOracleParameter = new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "pEndDate",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
        Value =   endDate
    };

    OracleParameter jobIdOracleParameter = new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "pJobId",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,                
        Value =   "123456"
    };

    using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ContextInfo.ConnectionString))
    {
        oracleConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            using (var oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(extractToRun, oracleConnection))
            {

                oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                oracleCommand.BindByName = true;
                oracleCommand.FetchSize = oracleCommand.FetchSize * 128;
                oracleCommand.InitialLONGFetchSize = 5000;
                oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(refCursorOracleParameter);
                oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(startDateOracleParameter);
                oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(endDateOracleParameter);
                oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(jobIdOracleParameter);

                using (OracleDataReader rdr = oracleCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    rdr.FetchSize = rdr.RowSize * 65536;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.MinimumCapacity = 400000;
                    dt.BeginLoadData();
                    dt.Load(rdr, LoadOption.Upsert);
                    dt.EndLoadData();
                    rdr.Close();
                    rdr.Dispose();
                    oracleCommand.Dispose();
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            oracleConnection.Close();
            oracleConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Processing the data:

```
public static void ExportDataTableToDelimitedFile(DataTable table, string filename, string encloseWith, string delimiter, bool includeHeader, string fieldsToExclude, bool fixedLengthValues)
{
    String excludeList = String.Empty;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldsToExclude))
    {
        excludeList = fieldsToExclude.ToUpper();
    }

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite, 2097152, FileOptions.None))
    {
        BinaryWriter sw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            sw.Write(String.Empty);
            sw.Close();
            sw.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        //Handle header
        if (includeHeader)
        {
            string header = String.Empty;
            String formattedHeader = String.Empty;
            foreach (DataColumn clm in table.Columns)
            {
                if (excludeList.Contains(clm.ColumnName.ToUpper()))
                    continue;

                if (clm.ColumnName.Length > 0)
                {
                    formattedHeader = String.Empty;
                    formattedHeader = encloseWith + clm.ColumnName + encloseWith;

                    if (header.Length > 0)
                        header = String.Join(delimiter, new string[] { header, formattedHeader });
                    else
                        header = formattedHeader;
                }
            }
            sw.Write(header);
        }
        // handle  values in data rows now
        Boolean hasEnlosedCharacter = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(encloseWith);
        Parallel.ForEach(table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(), row =>
        {
            char[] rowValue = new char[8192];
            Int32 rowValueIndex = 0;

            char[][] rowData = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString().ToCharArray()).ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < rowData.Length; i++)
            {
                Boolean useEnclosed = rowData[i].Length > 0 && hasEnlosedCharacter;
                if (rowValueIndex > 0)
                {
                    if (useEnclosed)
                    {
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = delimiter[0];
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = encloseWith[0];
                        rowData[i].CopyTo(rowValue, rowValueIndex);
                        rowValueIndex += rowData[i].Length;
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = encloseWith[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = delimiter[0];
                        rowData[i].CopyTo(rowValue, rowValueIndex);
                        rowValueIndex += rowData[i].Length;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (useEnclosed)
                    {
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = encloseWith[0];
                        rowData[i].CopyTo(rowValue, rowValueIndex);
                        rowValueIndex += rowData[i].Length;
                        rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = encloseWith[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rowData[i].CopyTo(rowValue, rowValueIndex);
                        rowValueIndex += rowData[i].Length;
                    }
                }
            }

            rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = '\r';
            rowValue[rowValueIndex++] = '\n';
            lock (sw)
            {
                sw.Write(rowValue, 0, rowValueIndex);
            }
        });
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
        table.Dispose();
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

There are several key points of note.  DataReader into a DataTable using Load is 40% faster than Dataset.Fill BUT don't set the fetchsize above 64K.  Performance degrades after that.  32K is probably about the best.  Character arrays are MUCH faster than even StringBuilder.  C# is crippled that we can't have Assembler subroutines, in my humble opinion.  I've considered writing a C++ dll just so I could have an Assembly language subroutine to copy memory around.  Then I wouldn't need to call ToCharArray().  Granted, I haven't looked at the IL to see exactly what ToCharArray() does but the performance analyzer points at that line of code as taking 26% of the time.

Surprisingly, these changes increase network utilization up to 4.5% (which is high for a single PC on a corporate network) AND it reduces the CPU utilization to around 80% because it's mainly now waiting on the disk write method instead of being busy copying strings around.

I didn't show the original code but it used to take 13-15 minutes to export the data to a pipe delimited file.  With these changes it takes 40-45 seconds to export exactly the same data.

I also didn't show that the original DB query had seven queries in it all union all together.  I broke those up so I could run them in parallel.  Performance fixes need to be addressed as a whole.  Many who tried to solve this problem before focused on the DB.  Nobody really focused on the client side and tried to identify what the real problem is.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Okay!  Here is a BETTER answer!

```
public static List<ROW_DATA> GetData(String extractToRun, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    List<ROW_DATA> dataTable = new List<ROW_DATA>();
    //RefCursor
    OracleParameter refCursorOracleParameter = new OracleParameter
                                            {
                                                ParameterName = "pCursor",
                                                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                                                OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor
                                            };

    OracleParameter startDateOracleParameter = new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "pStartDate",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
        Value =   startDate
    };

    OracleParameter endDateOracleParameter = new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "pEndDate",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
        Value =   endDate
    };

    OracleParameter jobIdOracleParameter = new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "pJobId",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,                
        Value =   "123456"
    };

    using (var oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(ContextInfo.ConnectionString))
    {
        oracleConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            using (var oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(extractToRun, oracleConnection))
            {

                oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                oracleCommand.BindByName = true;
                oracleCommand.FetchSize = oracleCommand.FetchSize * 128;
                oracleCommand.InitialLONGFetchSize = 5000;
                oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(refCursorOracleParameter);
                oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(startDateOracleParameter);
                oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(endDateOracleParameter);
                oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(jobIdOracleParameter);

                using (OracleDataReader rdr = oracleCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //byte[] columnBytes = new byte[16384];
                    Int32 tryCount = 0;
                    rdr.FetchSize = rdr.RowSize * 262144;
                            while (rdr.Read())
                            {
                                Int32 charLength = (Int32)rdr.GetChars(0, 0, null, 0, 0);
                                char[] colChars = new char[charLength];
                                rdr.GetChars(0, 0, colChars, 0, charLength);
                                //OracleString colValue = rdr.GetOracleString(0);
                                //int valueLength = colValue.Length;
                                //unsafe
                                //{
                                //    fixed (char* pcolValue = colValue.Value)
                                //    {
                                //        fixed (byte* pcolBytes = columnBytes)
                                //        {
                                //            for (int i = 0; i < valueLength; i++)
                                //            {
                                //                pcolBytes[i] = (byte)pcolValue[i];
                                //            }
                                //        }
                                //    }
                                //}
                                ROW_DATA rowData = new ROW_DATA { length = charLength, rowValues = colChars };
                                dataTable.Add(rowData);
                        }
                    }
                    rdr.Close();
                    rdr.Dispose();
                    oracleCommand.Dispose();
                    return dataTable;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            oracleConnection.Close();
            oracleConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I purposely left in the commented out code to show I even tried unsafe code to get the data into the format I needed.  Turns out, GetChars returns it just the way I want it so I can simply stream it to disk.  I'm up to 11% network utilization and 27 seconds to retrieve 413K rows and write them to disk.  I also modified the stored procedure to return a pipe delimited string so I only receive one column of data at the client.  It's really fast but I have ideas to cut the time in half.  Stay tuned.

Comment: This is modeled after my "make it go fast" pattern.

Comment: Use this information to your advantage to increase the performance of your app's when dealing with DB's.  I'm not going to show you what I did to the Oracle Stored Procedures which is obviously also important.  Ask Tom can educated you in that department.  Just know that Dataset.Fill is terrible in performance.

Comment: If you know the max character length GetChars will return then allocate a buffer of that length and only call GetChars once.  That will make it faster.